# Why is installing Tidyverse failing?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to 'R' and am trying to install 'Tidyverse' in a new RShiny project.

I am working on a Mac Book (Ventura 13.4 M1) and am using Rstudio (2023.06.1 Build 524)

> install.packages('tidyverse')

The install process fails with this error message:
Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here?

```
ld: library not found for -lfreetype
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [systemfonts.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘systemfonts’
* removing ‘/Users/xyz/R_Projects/RUrqis/renv/staging/1/systemfonts’
install of package 'systemfonts' failed [error code 1]
```

Comment: Look like you are installing from source? Try answering "no" when it asks if that's what you want to do.

Comment: You could try installing freetype, e.g., using homebrew: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/freetype